# Picasso large image download

Tags: android, bitmap, imagedownload, picasso, android-bitmap

I read about Picasso image downloading lib but there is one problem that I can't resolve it. It's large image downloading. When I have large image i.e 2000 x 1920 it's crushed (out of memory).

How could I solve this problem?

Picasso.with(context).load(myUrl).into(imageView);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(width, height)
```

Comment: You may also try `Picasso.with(context).load(url).fit().into(view)` to match exactly the size of your view.

Comment: after fit or resizing the image in ImageView becomes flattened, how to avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean flattened?